# TomEE + OpenJPA + IntelliJ entity doesn't persist

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I created a "Java EE Web Module" project in IntelliJ. I then wrote a JaxRS annotated class that accepts JSON input. I then populate an annotated entity with the data, and try to persist it using a managed persistence context.

```java
@Stateless
@Path("/states")
public class StateController {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testunit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Path("/session_new")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response session_new(final CustomerSessionRequest req) {
        CustomerSessions cs = new CustomerSessions(req.session_data);
        em.persist(cs);
        em.flush();
        System.out.println("New CustomerSession saved: " + cs.getCustomerSessionId());

        return Response.ok(cs).build();
    }
}
```

I have a data source configured within IntelliJ called "testdb", and a persistence unit named "testunit" that maps to that data source in the persistence tool window.

My persistence XML looks like this:

```
    <persistence-unit name="testunit">
        <jta-data-source>testdb</jta-data-source>
        <class>datamodels.testdb.CustomerSessions</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="testuser"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="testpassword"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Everything builds and deploys just fine, with no warnings. The request also runs just fine, and returns the expected response, with a new customer session ID generated.

However, nothing appears in the database.

So, my question: where is the data going, and how can I make the persist and flush calls work against my database?

EDIT:
I've tried several more things.

1) It looks like TomEE is using some kind of in-memory HSQL database with a data source name of "Default JDBC Data Source".
2) When I manually create the entity manager factory, and then the entity manager, everything works correctly:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testunit");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        CustomerSessions cs = new CustomerSessions(req.session_data);
        em.persist(cs);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("New CustomerSession saved: " + cs.getCustomerSessionId());
        return Response.ok(cs).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        return Response.serverError().entity("An exception occurred").build();
    }
```

2) If I try to create the `EntityManagerFactory` using the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation, the same initial problem occurs.

Comment: when you return the response, your browser can see the `response ok` status code ? Are your `transaction manager` configured correctly ? My doubt is its failing somewhere while commiting the transaction.

Comment: @Rp- yes, I'm testing with Postman in Chrome and the response is returned just fine, and the ID field is populated with a new ID. It frankly looks like there's a magical invisible database somewhere being saved to that I can't find.

I haven't written anything regarding TransactionManagers since I'm using a managed Persistence Context.

Comment: Also if this helps, when I stop the server I get these info messages: "Jan 27, 2014 10:02:39 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyResource
INFO: Closing DataSource: Default JDBC Database
Jan 27, 2014 10:02:39 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyResource
INFO: Closing DataSource: Default Unmanaged JDBC Database
J". I'd expect this to be my data source.

Comment: Do you have any `h2` or `hsqldb` related jars in your classpath? Try to remove them and try if they are failing with class not found exceptions.

Comment: Nope, unless TomEE brings those in on its own...

Comment: Where and what is configured in `testdb` of `<jta-data-source>testdb</jta-data-source>`. You either give a data source reference (like jndi) or put them in the properties. You have both in your case. Just remove the `<jta-data-source>testdb</jta-data-source>` and see

Comment: That was one of my many attempts to fix it. Removing it results in no difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46175/discussion-between-rp-and-jzila)

Comment: Thanks @Rp- for your help.

For anyone else who still wants to help, when I change the persistence context to application managed instead of container managed (i.e. when I create my own entityManagerFactory), it connects to the correct data source. But when I switch back to container managed, it uses the phantom one. Why, Java! Whyyyyyy?

Comment: you rather edit the question so that it may gain the attention of other users to help.

Comment: seems transactions aren't getting committed, you should manually commit them or try to configure datasource in tomee.xml/resources.xml as jta datasource.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid specifying data sources in tomee.xml/resources.xml since I want it to be dynamically deployable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two things I was missing:

1. I didn't specify `<Resource>` objects in tomee.xml (which I didn't
   want to, since I wanted it to deploy with the app). I discovered
   that this can be done in a `resources.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` or
   `META-INF` directories.
2. I didn't have the MySQL driver jar in the
   TomEE lib directory. Unfortunately TomEE was transparently loading
   the Default JDBC driver instead, causing entities to persist in its
   own magical database.

I still don't have an explanation for why application-managed (manually created) persistence contexts worked in the first place, but at least now I have it working consistently.